# SonarQube ignores pylint results

Tags: python, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to integrate pylint results with SonarQube.
To generate a report I use

```
pylint ./console/**/*.py --exit-zero --rcfile=.pylintrc > pylint-report.out
```

In `sonar-project.properties` I have:

```
sonar.python.pylint.reportPaths=pylint-report.out
```

(I tried `sonar.python.pylint.reportPath=pylint-report.out` also, as I saw some examples on the Internet with such a property).

Unfortunately, the sonar-scanner seems to ignore this setting.
I see no logs about `pylint` except:

```
10:56:18.516 DEBUG: 'PylintSensor' skipped because there is no related rule activated in the quality profile
10:56:18.517 DEBUG: 'PylintImportSensor' skipped because there is no related rule activated in the quality profile
```

But, as I understand this is not important if I generate a report on my own. Am I wrong?

What is a kind of surprise to me is there is no related log. For bandit result, for example, I get logs:

```
10:56:27.657 INFO: Sensor Import of Bandit issues [python]
10:56:27.658 INFO: Importing /home/gitlab-runner/builds/abcd/0/project/bandit-report.out
```

With the file or not a log entry is generated that the sonar-scaner at least tried to read the result. With pylint - nothing :(.

I am using SonarScanner 4.6.0.2311.
SonarServer is Version 8.3.1 (build 34397)
And I use default ruleset from the sonar.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was the version of sonarcube server.
After upgrading to 8.6.1 the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Since somebody have to still use version 8.3 of Sonar, you have to setup following in order sonar import your pylint report:

[image: Administration->Quality Profiles -> Python -> python-all-rules]